# Efficient way for pagination and count documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, pagination

I'm working on some simple table widget (on frontend) for presenting data with pagination.
So after filtering data from mongo db I need to count them before skipping and limiting. Is my way any near to efficient?

```
 var count = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("alarms").Find(filter).Count();
 var result = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("alarms").Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(limit).Skip(limit * (page - 1)).ToListAsync();
 var data = new BsonArray(result.Result);
 return new BsonDocument { { "data", data }, { "count", count } };
```

Answer (score 1):

For a running total, instead of performing a count query, can you not just assume the count with your page and limit parameters?

so...

```
var skip = limit * (page - 1);

var result = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("alarms")
    .Find(filter)
    .Sort(sort)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Limit(limit)
    .ToListAsync();

var data = new BsonArray(result.Result);
var count = (limit * (page - 1)) + result.Count(); 

return new BsonDocument { { "data", data }, { "count", count} };
```

Saved making that additional call for the count.

However, to retrieve a count of ALL matching documents for your filter you will need to perform an additional count as you are, which provided you have all the necessary indexes on your data, isn't terribly inefficient for what you want to achieve, seeing as the count is only returning an int, and no actual data from the collection.

Side note, you will want to Skip() before you Limit()

Comment: I need whole colection count so I can make buttons like "jump to page 10" etc. Your method when I'm on page 1 and take 10 records produces count = 10*0+10 = 10 instead of 27k records after filtering.

Comment: Indeed, if you want the full number of records in the collection to provide links for every page they can jump to you will need to retrieve it separately. Apologies i misunderstood, the code i gave you was for a running total and works as it should - Your limit is 10, your page is 1 and the number of records returned is 10, hence [10*0+10] = 10, where as if you were on page 2, it would be [10*1+10] = 20. If you were to jump to page 10, it would just be [10*9+10] = 100. Which, if your limit is 10, is correct